# Use Either with Future

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, functional-programming, async-await

I want to use `dartz` functional style and do something like this:

```
Either<Failure, Response> result = await remoteDataSource.request() // Future<Response> request();
    .then((response) => Right(response))
    .catchError((failure) => Left(failure));
```

But it seems that I can't do this:

> error: A value of type 'Right< dynamic, Response>' can't be assigned to
>   a variable of type 'Either< Failure, Response>'.

So, how can I use `Either` with `Future` this way?

Answer (score 2):

It's all about `<generics>`.

```dart
.then((response) => Right(response)) // this is of type Right<dynamic,User>
```

You got to give the compiler all the proper information:

```dart
.then((response) => Right<Failure, Response>(response))

// or

.then((response) => right(response)) // a helper function which returns an Either
```

Comment: Helped a lot bro, ty